# Unable to inspect the Arrow and Down button through any approach in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Need to inspect the arrow up and down option in the input field

Comment: give some more detail like what have you tried, what error are you getting and what is the arrow and down button which you are trying ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use instead **sendKeys()** to send arrow up and down

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
```

it will increase the input or decrease it if you used the arrow down.

I hope this could help.

Comment: Muhammad, it not working as driver is unable to perform key up and down action

Answer (score 0):

When your `<input>` control is of type "number", each browser will interpret it as spin box and display an input box with up-down controls. These up-down controls are not inserted into HTML; hence you can't spy on it.

Comment: Damian, thanks for the information but i am unable to write anything in this field. Is there any way through which i can write in this input field